# Linq filtering many to many query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to filter a query but the result is incorrect. I am filtering PromotionMajorChains which is a many relationship but the result is giving me 2 promotion major chains when it should only return 1 "Fruit and Veg City". Both promotion major chains is linked to the same promotionId.

**Promotion table**

[image]

**PromotionMajorChain table**

[image]

Code

```
var paginatedQueryable = _dbContext.Promotions.Where(x => x.PromotionMajorChains.Any(c => c.MajorChain.Contains("Fruit and Veg City")));
```

Comment: What LINQ are you using? LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What database provider? It seems like you are using one of the EFs and expect the `Where` to filter the relationship from `Promotions` but EF doesn't do that until EF Core 5.x. Your query filters you to one `Promotions` and that is linked to two `PromotionMajorChains` which is correct.

Comment: While there are several ways you could resolve this, the simplest if you query from another side of the relationship : `var q = from promotionMajorChain in _dbContext.PromotionMajorChains where promotionMajorChain.MajorChain.Contains("Fruit and Veg City") select promotionMajorChain.Promotion;`